# Change a WebDriver::Wait instance's timeout after instantiation

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, wait

I'm wondering if the following is possible somehow:

```
@wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new timeout: 10
# ...do stuff...

# Stuff gets really slow here. Better increase the timeout.
def janky_method()
    old_timeout = @wait.timeout
    @wait.timeout += 50
    e = @wait.until { @selenium.find_element :css, 'div#page-loads-rock' }
    @wait.timeout = old_timeout
    e
end
```

So far, the only solution I've seen is to spin up a new `Wait` driver. Can I change the timeout for the existing one instead?

Comment: why you need so? knowing that probably we can think of another work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Selenium::WebDriver::Wait class does not provide any methods for modifying the timeout (ie `@timeout` variable).

If you want to be able to modify it, you will have to monkey patch the Selenium::WebDriver::Wait class:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
class Selenium::WebDriver::Wait
  attr_accessor :timeout
end
```

This would then allow you to interact with the `@timeout` variable as you have done in the `janky_method`.

Note: I am not sure that there is a benefit of this approach over just creating a new wait for the specific scenario.